# How to check TR is hidden or has class 'display:none' from TD's a's i's id

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a very weird situation where I have assigned attribute `id` to the TD  . From this `id` I want to check whether TR id `hidden` or `visible`.

```
<table id="tableID" class="tableClass">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="3px">Header1</th>
        <th align="left">Header2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td><a <i id="1">></i></a>Data2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have tried this

`document.getElementById(id).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.hidden` but its giving `false` all time even if it hidden by using `hide()`.

**Console:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using ID [Selector ("#id")](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) with [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) using [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/hemoqeqoji/edit?html,js,console,output)**

```
isVisible = $('#' + id).closest('tr').is(':visible');
```

HTML correction

Your html is also invalid, you missed the closing angle bracket `>` of anchor `a` tag and probable you want Data2 within `i` tag.

*Change*

```
<td><a <i id="1"> </i></a>Data2</td>
```

*To*

```
<td><a> <i id="1">Data2 </i></a></td>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery added in your application, see this, https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ Also check if you are getting errors? let me know when and how this script gets executed

Comment: Every thing is fine. plz see update i have added image

Comment: You need to add # before id in id selector

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>sample Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btncheck').click(function () {

                alert($('#1').closest('tr').css('display'))
            });



        });


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="check" id="btncheck" />
   <table id="tableID" class="tableClass">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="3px">Header1</th>
        <th align="left">Header2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="display:none">
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td><a <i id="1"> </i></a>&nbsp;Gautam Dutt</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
       </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tried giving undefined

Comment: first intitialze with style="display:none" or style="display:block"